# I’m trying to understand Microsoft Graph API’s rate limiting/throttling with OneDrive/SharePoint and excel endpoints

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, throttling, rate-limiting

I’m trying to understand Microsoft Graph API’s rate limiting/throttling with OneDrive/SharePoint and excel endpoints. I know that they don’t publish these limits ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online#why-cant-you-just-tell-me-the-exact-throttling-limits)), but am hoping that if I provide some information about my use-case, someone might be able to provide ballpark figures.

Here is some information about the use case:

1. There is a spreadsheet that is kept in OneDrive or SharePoint
2. This spreadsheet runs calculations
3. Users send in inputs and get back outputs from this spreadsheet
4. There are 200 users
5. Each user makes about 10 read requests (sending in inputs) and 10
   write requests(getting back outputs) per day i.e. 2,000 read requests and 2,000 write requests per day

Given the information above, is there any way to know if users will encounter the `429 ("Too many requests") or 503 ("Server Too Busy")` error?

And if so,:

1. How often?
2. Is there a strategy for dealing with this?

I'm ultimately trying to decide if this is an appropriate tool for an enterprise-grade app or if I should go with SpreadsheetWeb.

Comment: Please go through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#excel-service-limits).

Comment: When you implement error handling, use the HTTP error code 429 to detect throttling. The failed response includes the Retry-After response header. Backing off requests using the Retry-After delay is the best way to recover from throttling because Microsoft Graph continues to log resource usage while a client is being throttled.

(1) Wait the number of seconds specified in the Retry-After header. (2) Retry the request. (3) If the request fails again with a 429 error code, you are still being throttled. Continue to use the recommended Retry-After delay and retry the request until it succeeds.